# Cannot call ViewPagerAdapter constructor in android

Tags: android, constructor, fragment, this, tablayout

SO I came up with this issue having viewpager adpater constructor not being recognized in my main activity which is basically a service, extends InputMethodService

Now the issue is it cannot recognize the viewpager adapter  constructor which I created and shows this error,
'ViewPagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity)' in 'com.example.replymind.ViewPagerAdapter' cannot be applied to '(com.example.replymind.RMinputMethod)'

issue in this line:

```
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
```

this is my viewpageradapater class

```
package com.example.replymind;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0: return new ReplyLengthFragment();
            default: return new ReplyLengthFragment();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Tried to implement ViewPagerAdapter class and it showed error in my service class

Comment: It's not the service's responsibility to initialize the fragment.